# Laravel return false when upload file with S3 Endpoint (Custom domain)

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, laravel-storage

I have working upload file feature with AWS,

This is my code for upload file

```
    /**
     * Create image and save it to storage.
     *
     * @param  string $key
     * @param  string $relation
     * @return void
     */
    public function createImage(string $key, $relation = 'image')
    {
        if ($file = request()->file) {
            $image = Storage::put('/news', $file);

            $this->image()->create([
                'filename' => $image,
                'url' => Storage::url($image)
            ]);
        }
    }
```

below my config on `.env`:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=key
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=secret
AWS_BUCKET=cdn.example.com
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=ap-southeast-1
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false
```

With those configuration, I was able to upload the files to bucket.
Then I enabled **Static website hosting** and create CNAME with same name as the bucket (cdn.example.com). Until this step, it is still works, but **my purpose is to make the Storage::put() function return the url like 'https://cdn.example.com/news/test.jpg'**, (currently: https://s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/cdn.example.com/images/news/test.jpg.

I change the config like this

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=key
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=secret
AWS_BUCKET=cdn.example.com
AWS_ENDPOINT=https://cdn.example.com
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=ap-southeast-1
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=true
```

When I try to upload the file, the Storage::put() return false. If the `AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT` changed to `false`, the upload is working again.

So the problem is **use_path_style_endpoint**. Anyone knows the solution? Do I need addtional setting on the bucket?

Comment: add ``AWS_URL=https://cdn.example.com`` and it should return the file url with the specified domain. and you don't need ``AWS_ENDPOINT``

Comment: @OMiShah, wow, you are right. Thats work, I think I'm following wrong tutorial.